# JMeter does not perform Thread Group infinite

Tags: jmeter

I have a Test Plan with inside a Thread Group set with 1 thread and Loop Count to "Infinite".

In the Thread Group I inserted a BeanShell Preprocessor to print a log in the shell. The expectation is that the test will iterate printing the log, but it stops immediately and the log is not printed.
In logs I can see that the thread is started, but nothing in Thread Group is performed.
Below the output of execution:

```
2021-05-04 15:03:44,962 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2021-05-04 15:03:44,965 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2021-05-04 15:03:44,972 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2021-05-04 15:03:45,121 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2021-05-04 15:03:45,121 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2021-05-04 15:03:45,121 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2021-05-04 15:03:45,121 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2021-05-04 15:03:45,140 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2021-05-04 15:03:45,136 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2021-05-04 15:03:45,142 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2021-05-04 15:03:45,144 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2021-05-04 15:03:45,144 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2021-05-04 15:03:45,150 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2021-05-04 15:03:45,150 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Preprocessors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors) executed per sample in scope, if there are no samples nothing will be executed

> Preprocessors are used to modify the Samplers in their scope.

Either add sampler or change to JSR223/BeanShell sampler instead Preprocessor